# Vertically moving textview on append text

Tags: android, textview

I am working on android music related application which basically reads the specific lrc file from storage while music is being played. When the song is loaded the lyrics are also read and stored in `arraylist<LyricObject>.` `LyricObject` contains the lyric line and specific minute and seconds when the lyric is to be displayed. I managed to show previous lyric + current lyric + next lyric at a time. When current lyric is displayed, previous and next lyrics are updated as well accordingly. What I want is to keep the lyrics/text which I also want to scroll vertically in a `TextView` even when the song ends. Currently I can do this

```
 textview.append(currentlyric + " \n" + textview.getText());
```

I want to show lyrics like at the end of movie where they show credits and highlight the currently speaking lyric (by scrolling to specific position according to lyric time).

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: would someone mind giving the reason of down voting? I want to know whats wrong with the question. and btw I still havn't got any solution

Answer (score 0):

https://www.wikihow.com/Make-an-*.Lrc-File

you can edit lrc file  with your requirement...understand what time and what data run ....copy one or two portion...paste in bottom...edit that time with your time and paste your data that you show at that time..save it and run

maybe it help

Comment: I think my question is different. anyhow thanks for your reply